# Cannot debug single theory in isolation

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xunit.net, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to debug an individual theory in Visual Studio 2017? This worked in 2015. Now, in 2017, starts the debugger and kicks off all test cases in the theory.

I just updated the latest release of 2017 (15.9.7). Not sure if it worked beforehand.

I can choose an individual test, but when I click debug, they are all executed. [image: Test runner screenshot]

This works in Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3). The issue persists in Visual Studio 2019 preview 1.1.

Shortened code sample:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class PayloadTest : BaseTest
    {
        [InlineData("AllergyDataChanged")]
        [InlineData("ImplantableDeviceDataChanged")]
        public void test1(string source, Type entityIdType = null)
        {
            TestSubscriber(source, entityIdType);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Go to: Tools > Options > Test > General > Uncheck "Discover tests in real time from source files"

This appears to be an issue with Visual Studio 2017+.

[Source of quote is a response a received on Github](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/749#issuecomment-468720299)